# Me sale un error de permisos al abrir cualquier programa o ejecutar comandos en Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, filesystem, fedora

Estuve hace días haciendo unas configuraciones en el sistema por otros problemas que tuve, pero **desde ese día he estado teniendo problemas con Ubuntu no me deja abrir ningun programa ni hacer casi ningun comando en la terminal** porque me da un problema de permisos aunque lo ejecute con sudo.
Al parecer creo que por algunos comandos delicados que hice ese día se eliminaron archivos importantes del sistema pero nose como arreglarlo

Este es el error

[image: error imagen]

> Configuration file "/home/steven/.config/konsolerc" not writable.
> Please contact your system administrator.

Cuando escribo algunos comandos en la terminal me sale esto:

```
/snap/code/85/electron-launch: línea 28:/home/steven/snap/code/common/.cache/gdk-pixbuf-loaders.cache: Sistemade archivos de solo lectura
```

¿Qué puedo hacer? :/

Comment: El sistema de archivos está en modo de solo lectura. Revisa [esta pregunta](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135389/how-to-fix-read-only-file-system-on-18-04) en askubuntu, podría servirte.